# Printing in java doesn't complete in windows 7

Tags: java, swing

When i print something by java application in windows 7 the output is blank page and the last graphic only is printed but when i print it in windows 10 it printed successfully .. so i don't no why this happen in windows 7 specially it was printing before on windows 7 and suddenly it happen what i told before (blank page)

this is my code and the output in the picture below

```
    public void printed_bill_printing() {
    totals_panelB.setVisible(true);
    footer_panelB.setVisible(true);

    int count_rows = tableEB.getRowCount();
    int count = 0;
    int table_height = 0;
    while (count <= count_rows - 1) {
        int row_height = tableEB.getRowHeight(count);
        table_height = row_height + table_height;
        count++;
    }


    float widtha = scrollPaneEB.getWidth();
    float heighta = table_height + 30;

    scrollPaneEB.setSize(Math.round(widtha), Math.round(heighta));

    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    final int finalTable_height = table_height;
    printJob.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        @Override
        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

            if (pageIndex > 0) {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            paint_PF.scale(.68, .6);
            B.print(paint_PF);

            Graphics2D paint_table = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            paint_table.translate(1, 430);
            paint_table.scale(.68, 1);
            scrollPaneB.setVisible(false);
            scrollPaneEB.print(paint_table);

            Graphics2D paint_egmaly = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            paint_egmaly.translate(1, finalTable_height + tableEB.getTableHeader().getHeight() + 2);
            paint_egmaly.scale(1.45, 1);
            totals_panelB.setVisible(false);
            totals_panelB.print(paint_egmaly);


            Graphics2D paint_tawke3 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            paint_tawke3.translate(0, 200);
            footer_panelB.setVisible(false);
            footer_panelB.print(paint_tawke3);

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });

    PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttrSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    printRequestAttrSet.add(new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 350, 500, MediaPrintableArea.MM));
    printRequestAttrSet.add(Chromaticity.MONOCHROME);

    try {
        PrintService ps = findPrintService(String.valueOf(printer1PST_combo.getSelectedItem()));
        printJob.setPrintService(ps);
        printJob.print(printRequestAttrSet);
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {

    }
    adapt_table_size(scrollPaneEB, 440, 351);

}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to verify this without a [mre], but most likely the problem is that you are modifying the original Graphics object.  `Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics;` does not create a different Graphics2D object;  you’re scaling the original print Graphics.  `Graphics2D paint_table = (Graphics2D) graphics;` then uses that scaled Graphics object.  And so on for all of your painting.  Consider using [Graphics.create](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#create%28%29) (but remember to call `dispose()` for each create!).

Comment: can you modify my code because i don't understand you ,please ?

Comment: `Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();` followed by your two lines of drawing, followed by `paint_PF.dispose();`.  **The dispose() call is important;**  do not omit it.

Comment: @VGR thank you very much it works .. but with method .create() which you told me that i should use it but i used dispose() and it works

Answer (score 0):

Casting a Graphics object does not create a new Graphics object.  You repeatedly cast the Graphics object and place it in new variables, but it’s still the same Graphics object, so your changes are cumulative.

Stepping through the code:

```
Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

This causes paint_PF to contain the *same print Graphics object* that was passed to the method.  It is referring to the graphics object as a Graphics2D, but it’s still the same object.

```
paint_PF.scale(.68, .6);
B.print(paint_PF);
```

Now the *original print Graphics object* is at 0.68 by 0.6 scale.

```
Graphics2D paint_table = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

Again, this is the same Graphics object, which the code just set to have a 0.68 by 0.6 scale.

```
paint_table.translate(1, 430);
paint_table.scale(.68, 1);
```

The print Graphics object is still scaled by 0.68 by 0.6;  now you are scaling it *further* by 0.68, resulting in a Graphics object which is actually scaled by 0.04624 by 0.6 (because 0.68 × 0.68 = 0.04624).

```
scrollPaneB.setVisible(false);
scrollPaneEB.print(paint_table);

Graphics2D paint_egmaly = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

paint_egmaly still contains the original print Graphics object.

```
paint_egmaly.translate(1, finalTable_height + tableEB.getTableHeader().getHeight() + 2);
paint_egmaly.scale(1.45, 1);
```

Now your print Graphics has been scaled, scaled again, translated, and scaled yet again.

```
totals_panelB.setVisible(false);
totals_panelB.print(paint_egmaly);


Graphics2D paint_tawke3 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
```

paint_tawke3 contains the original graphics object, with all of the previous scaling and translation.

```
paint_tawke3.translate(0, 200);
```

Now the Graphics object has been scaled, scaled, translated, scaled, and translated again.

```
footer_panelB.setVisible(false);
footer_panelB.print(paint_tawke3);
```

One way to make your changes to the Graphics temporary is by creating a new Graphics object, using [Graphics.create](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#create%28%29), then apply your changes to that.  If you do this, you are responsible for deallocating the Graphics object by calling its [dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#dispose%28%29) method.

```
Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
paint_PF.scale(.68, .6);
B.print(paint_PF);
paint_PF.dispose();     // DO NOT FORGET THIS

Graphics2D paint_table = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
paint_table.translate(1, 430);
paint_table.scale(.68, 1);
scrollPaneB.setVisible(false);
scrollPaneEB.print(paint_table);
paint_table.dispose();  // DO NOT FORGET THIS

Graphics2D paint_egmaly = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
paint_egmaly.translate(1, finalTable_height + tableEB.getTableHeader().getHeight() + 2);
paint_egmaly.scale(1.45, 1);
totals_panelB.setVisible(false);
totals_panelB.print(paint_egmaly);
paint_egmaly.dispose(); // DO NOT FORGET THIS


Graphics2D paint_tawke3 = (Graphics2D) graphics.create();
paint_tawke3.translate(0, 200);
footer_panelB.setVisible(false);
footer_panelB.print(paint_tawke3);
paint_tawke3.dispose(); // DO NOT FORGET THIS
```

Another option, which uses fewer resources, is to restore the transform of the Graphics object after each change:

```
AffineTransform originalTransform = ((Graphics2D) graphics).getTransform();

Graphics2D paint_PF = (Graphics2D) graphics;
paint_PF.scale(.68, .6);
B.print(paint_PF);
paint_PF.setTransform(originalTransform);

Graphics2D paint_table = (Graphics2D) graphics;
paint_table.translate(1, 430);
paint_table.scale(.68, 1);
scrollPaneB.setVisible(false);
scrollPaneEB.print(paint_table);
paint_table.setTransform(originalTransform);

Graphics2D paint_egmaly = (Graphics2D) graphics;
paint_egmaly.translate(1, finalTable_height + tableEB.getTableHeader().getHeight() + 2);
paint_egmaly.scale(1.45, 1);
totals_panelB.setVisible(false);
totals_panelB.print(paint_egmaly);
paint_egmaly.setTransform(originalTransform);


Graphics2D paint_tawke3 = (Graphics2D) graphics;
paint_tawke3.translate(0, 200);
footer_panelB.setVisible(false);
footer_panelB.print(paint_tawke3);
paint_tawke3.setTransform(originalTransform);
```